# Windows Store Mising

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I am running a Windows 10 Lite version of 1803 that does not include "Windows Store".  Is there a way to install the Windows Store into a distro that does not include W.S.?

Comment: You could probably update to 1809 using the standard install media from Microsoft.

Comment: m"Lite version of 1803 " Where did you download this?

Comment: I downloaded 1803 lite from the net.  It runs great and is very lite.  I saved a copy of the ISO in case I have to reinstall.  I don't want the bloated 1809.